# Replacing strings in stream, using Swizzle Stream

Tags: java, replace, stream

I've tried the Swizzle Stream library to replace tokens in an input stream.

```
  String RESOURCE_PATH = "FakePom.xml";
  InputStream pomIS = JarFinderServlet.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( RESOURCE_PATH );

  if( null == pomIS )
     throw new MavenhoeException("Can't read fake pom template - getResourceAsStream( RESOURCE_PATH ) == null");

  Map map = ArrayUtils.toMap(  new String[][]{
     {"@GRP@", artifactInfo.getGroup() },
     {"@ART@", artifactInfo.getName() },
     {"@VER@", artifactInfo.getVersion() },
     {"@PACK@", artifactInfo.getPackaging() },
     {"@NAME@", artifactInfo.getFileName() },
     {"@DESC@", req.getQueryString() },
  } );


  //  This does not replace anything, no idea why. //
  ReplaceStringsInputStream replacingIS = new ReplaceStringsInputStream(pomIS, map);
  ReplaceStringInputStream replacingIS2 = new ReplaceStringInputStream(pomIS, "@VER@", "0.0-AAAAA");
  ReplaceStringInputStream replacingIS3 = new ReplaceStringInputStream(pomIS, "@", "#");

  ServletOutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
  IOUtils.copy( replacingIS, os );
  replacingIS.close();
```

This did not work. It just does not replace. So I resorted to the "PHP way"...

```
  String pomTemplate = IOUtils.toString(pomIS)
  .replace("@GRP@", artifactInfo.getGroup() )
  .replace("@ART@", artifactInfo.getName() )
  .replace("@VER@", artifactInfo.getVersion() )
  .replace("@PACK@", artifactInfo.getPackaging() )
  .replace("@NAME@", artifactInfo.getFileName() )
  .replace("@DESC@", req.getQueryString() );

  ServletOutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
  IOUtils.copy( new StringInputStream(pomTemplate), os );
  os.close();
```

Works.

What's wrong?

Comment: code looks ok, might be time to step into it with a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IOUtils.copy calls read(byte[]) method instead of read(), which is overridden by FixedTokenReplacementInputStream, a superclass of ReplaceStringInputStream.
You should implement copying on your own, for example, as follows:

```
try {
int b;
while ((b = pomIS.read()) != -1) {
    os.write(b);
}} finally { os.flush();os.close(); }
```

Comment: Oh... so Swizzle has inconsistent API, that is :)  Thanks for pointing out, this really didn't cross my mind at all.

Comment: Ran into this myself today.  Bug fixed.  Should appear in 1.6.2 in a few days.